# Postgres filtered WITH query

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I currently have the following query:

```
WITH instances AS (
    SELECT b.ldtc as date, a.fk_item_id, b.movement, a.quantity, 
        CASE WHEN b.movement = 'Inbound' THEN a.quantity ELSE -a.quantity END as absquantity
    FROM inventory_resupplylogiteminstance a
    INNER JOIN inventory_resupplylog b ON b.uid = a.fk_resupply_log_id
)

SELECT a.name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.date < ('2018-10-10'::date) THEN b.absquantity END) as starting_balance,

    SUM(CASE WHEN b.date > ('2018-10-10'::date) AND b.date < ('2018-10-12'::date) AND b.movement = 'aa' THEN b.absquantity END) as aa,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.date > ('2018-10-10'::date) AND b.date < ('2018-10-12'::date) AND b.movement = 'bb' THEN b.absquantity END) as bb,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.date > ('2018-10-10'::date) AND b.date < ('2018-10-12'::date) AND b.movement = 'cc' THEN b.absquantity END) as cc,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.date > ('2018-10-10'::date) AND b.date < ('2018-10-12'::date) AND b.movement = 'dd' THEN b.absquantity END) as dd,

    SUM(CASE WHEN b.date < ('2018-10-12'::date) THEN b.absquantity END) AS ending_balance




FROM inventory_item a
LEFT JOIN instances b ON b.fk_item_id = a.uid

GROUP BY a.uid, a.name
ORDER BY a.name
```

As you can see, the 2nd-5th SUM lines are redundant in that they're querying for rows where `b.date` is between `2018-10-10` and `2018-10-12`. Is there any way to rewrite my query so as to only have to write `b.date > ('2018-10-10'::date) AND b.date < ('2018-10-12'::date)` once and still be able to SELECT `starting_balance` and `ending_balance` on the same row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the range in the CTE and create a flag that indicates if the row is in the indicated range.

Then you can use that flag in the final SELECT. Switching to a `FILTER ()` expression also makes it more readable:

```
WITH instances AS (
  SELECT b.ldtc as date, 
         a.fk_item_id, 
         b.movement, 
         a.quantity, 
         CASE 
           WHEN b.movement = 'Inbound' THEN a.quantity 
           ELSE -a.quantity 
         END as absquantity,
         -- the column in_range returns either true or false
         (b.ldtc > ('2018-10-10'::date) AND b.date < ('2018-10-12'::date)) as in_range
  FROM inventory_resupplylogiteminstance a
    INNER JOIN inventory_resupplylog b ON b.uid = a.fk_resupply_log_id
)
SELECT a.name, 
       SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where b.date < '2018-10-10'::date) as starting_balance,
       SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where in_range and b.movement = 'aa') as aa,
       SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where in_range and b.movement = 'bb') as bb,
       SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where in_range and b.movement = 'cc') as cc,
       SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where in_range and b.movement = 'dd') as dd,
       SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where b.date < '2018-10-12'::date) AS ending_balance
FROM inventory_item a
  LEFT JOIN instances b ON b.fk_item_id = a.uid
GROUP BY a.uid, a.name
ORDER BY a.name;
```

If you don't want to repeat the date for the starting and ending balance either, you can put the range you want to test for into the CTE, then use Postgres' [range functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) in the final query:

```
WITH instances AS (
  SELECT b.ldtc as date, 
         a.fk_item_id, 
         b.movement, 
         a.quantity, 
         CASE 
           WHEN b.movement = 'Inbound' THEN a.quantity 
           ELSE -a.quantity 
         END as absquantity,
         daterange('2018-10-10'::date, '2018-10-12'::date, '()') as check_range
  FROM inventory_resupplylogiteminstance a
    INNER JOIN inventory_resupplylog b ON b.uid = a.fk_resupply_log_id
)
SELECT a.name, 
    SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where b.date < lower(check_range)) as starting_balance,
    SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where b.date <@ b.check_range and b.movement = 'aa') as aa,
    SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where b.date <@ b.check_range and b.movement = 'bb') as bb,
    SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where b.date <@ b.check_range and b.movement = 'cc') as cc,
    SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where b.date <@ b.check_range and b.movement = 'dd') as dd,
    SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where b.date < upper(b.check_range))) AS ending_balance
FROM inventory_item a
  LEFT JOIN instances b ON b.fk_item_id = a.uid
GROUP BY a.uid, a.name
ORDER BY a.name;
```

`daterange('2018-10-10'::date, '2018-10-12'::date, '()')` creates a [date range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY) where the two dates are **excluded**.

The `<@` operator tests if a date falls into the given range.

So the expression `b.date <@ b.check_range` is equivalent to `b.date > '2018-10-10'::date AND b.date < '2018-10-12'::date` (because the range was defined excluding the edges)

Comment: Wow, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, this is so clean! Definitely way better than what I came up with. Question though, I noticed you replaced

`SUM(CASE WHEN b.date < ('2018-10-10'::date) THEN b.absquantity END) as starting_balance`

with

`SUM(b.absquantity) filter (where b.date < lower(check_range)) as starting_balance`

I realize they do the same thing but I want to know if the latter is more efficient or simply just something you prefer in terms of readability